# Why isn't this Custom Javascript Macro in Google Tag Manager returning the expected results?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to build a custom macro in GTM that runs through two datalayers and builds a list for a 3rd party tag.

This is in the data layers:

```
'cartSkus': [ '12345','56789' ]
'cartQuantities': [ 1,3 ]
```

The Custom Javascript Macro:

```
function() {
List = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < {{cartSkus}}.length; i++) {
List += "agent.addOrderItemQtySubtotal(\"" + {{cartSkus}}[i] + "\",\"" + {{cartQuantities}}[i] + "\") ";
}

return List;
}
```

This is how I am using it in the tag:

```
{{CustomList}}
```

I expect to see:

```
agent.addCartItemQtySubtotal("12345","1"); 
agent.addCartItemQtySubtotal("56789","3");
```

However when fired, the source of the page only shows:

```
google_tag_manager["GTM-TD6ZG9"].macro('gtm1413986172883')
```

I am a bit out of my depth in this, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you type `google_tag_manager["GTM-TD6ZG9"].macro('gtm1413986172883')` into the console?

Comment: If you are referring to the debug console, I am not sure how to type anything new in that window. However, I do see the expected value in the Macro CustomList. I'm now wondering if there is a different way I am supposed to call that macro to show rather than just {{CustomList}} in the tag within GTM.